# how can I specifiy xctool parameters in travis.yaml?

Tags: travis-ci, xctool

For compiling my objective-c project I need to be able to specify xctool parameters configuration and destination.
How can I do this in .travis.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: use **xctool_args**